# Flutter Firebase delay function

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, delayed-execution

I am creating an event booking app with Flutter and Firebase Firestore. And sometimes if events are popular there is a possibility that a user buys a ticket and gets no seat because somebody was faster, and because of that I want to create a reservation before the purchase that is applied for 5 minutes and if the user doesn't buy within that time range the ticket reservation will be automatically deleted. Can someone give me a suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give an answer without knowing your data structure and the business requirements, so here's one way to do it with few assumption:

- Assuming you've a document for each seat, let's called `SeatDocument`.
- `SeatDocument` has a field called status that can be set to `available`, `blocked`, or `sold`.
- Whenever a user is in the session to buy a ticket, no one else can purchase the same ticket for that seat.

In this scenario, whenever a user enters a session to book a ticket, you should use a transaction to:

- retrieve the `SeatDocument`.
- make sure its status is `available`.
- mark it as `blocked`.

Using a transaction here prevents two users from entering a session for the same ticket, and allow you to do multiple operations while making sure you have the correct data.

If the user ends up buying the ticket, you can mark it as `sold`. If the five minutes passes, you can end the user session from the client side and mark the ticket as `available`.

You've to determine the process based on the business requirement but this is a rough idea of how it can be implemented.

If you're unfamiliar with transaction, here's a useful reference and a video that explains it:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

===== update based on the comment ===

You can create a cloud function that triggers whenever the ticket status has changed. In the trigger function, you'll get the `SeatDocument` where you can check if the status changed to `blocked`. If so, then you can create a `Scheduled function` that will run after 5 minutes and check if the status has changed to `sold`. And if not, then you can update the ticket status back to `available`.

In short, you can do a lot with both `Triggers` and `Schedule Functions` from Cloud Functions. You can also look into `callableFunctions` that you can use to start a session and to sell a ticket from the server side of Cloud Functions.

- [schedule-functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)
- [triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)
- [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

Comment: Thank you I got your point. Currently I have a int in firestore that looks like this "ticketsQuantity: 50" but I can implement it to your suggestions. What I am worried about is that the tickets are marked as blocked and the user disconnects from the app and then they will stay as blocked so I have to make this delayed function stuff server side but that is way above my knowledge. Do you have an idea how to make it Serverside?

Comment: I guess that works but what if I have 100 events with 10 000 Tickets then I need and array with 10 000 fields and different Statuses I guess all that reads and writes are extremly expensive arent they?

Comment: @EnviroApps You get 20k writes and 50k reads for free per day. You should do the math per session. It should not be expensive if each ticket has its own document. If each session has 10 reads and 10 writes, that's still less than 1 cent. If you're selling 100,000 tickets, you really should not be worried about that.

Comment: Ok thank you I gonna accept your answer but to sum it up: I have to create an array and each item inside the array has its own status("Available","Sold", "Blocked") if a user starts the booking process I am going to run a chedule function that sets the status first to blocked and if the user doesnt buy within the 5 mins to available right? And if the user buys I have to cancel the function. Is that all possbile with cloud functions, flutter and firebase?

Comment: Yes, the document should have a field called `status` where it has one of the three values. You don't need a schedule function to set the status to block, you can set it by the user. You need the schedule function to make sure the status is not blocked after 5 minutes from the beginning of the session. Once the user block a ticket, a cloud trigger should create the schedule function to make sure it's not blocked after 5 minutes (since that's what you were worried about in the first comment)

Comment: Ok one more question how can I determine what status is older than 5 mins because the trigger will set everything to available right?

Comment: @EnviroApps You need to familiarize yourself with triggers. The trigger will only give you the document that has changed, not all the documents. You can also add the timestamp to the ticket document such as `lastUpdatedTime`. Don't put all the tickets under one document, firestore has a 1mb limit per document anyway and also has 10k limit per fields I believe. Make sure each ticket has its own document.

Comment: What do you mean by session is there a way to determine what session is older than 5 mins?

Comment: @EnviroApps if you add `lastUpdatedTime` field to each document and update it every time you update the document, you can query all the documents that are older than 5 minutes and their status is `blocked`. By session I mean once I user set a document to blocked until it's either sold or become available again.

Comment: Oh thats a very nice idea so I just take a cron job that checks every 5 minutes if the field lastUpdatedTime is older than 5 minutes right?

Comment: @EnviroApps yes, there are many ways to do the same thing. You need to decide at the end based on what you see fit from the available options.

Comment: Because you are talking about using a document do you think it makes more sense to create a document for each ticket with a status field and a lastUpdatedTime field?

Comment: @EnviroApps yes, create a document for each ticket with those fields and other info. Much easier to handle, and you'll have no limitation when you have a lot of tickets. You should check firestore document limitations.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I doubt cloud functions would cut it in this case. Ideally you would be handling such things on the backend server (in Google Cloud Run for example). Apps on devices as clients only and the backend handles the tickets logic, communicates with the Firestore and so on. It would be safer than making assumptions based on 5 minutes wakeup or anything.

Say your user starts the app, app can init on the backend which will pull up the data for particular user (also good idea to store all the data for booked tickets, some history etc. accessible only by the backend server).

Plus if you plan to make sales in your app, having a backend to check purchases via Google API is pretty much a must.

As for the general logic:

1. App (client) sends request to the backend that the user wants to buy a ticket.
2. Backend checks for the number of tickets left.
3. Backend removes one ticket from the total count till all the "paperwork" (processing details, payment and so on) is done.
4. If everything is okay - user gets confirmation, backend does necessary work on the database (Firestore)

If something is NOT okay - payment didn't go through for example (it happens A LOT) - the user get a message, the backend adds the ticket back to the pool.

What type of datastructure you want to have is up to you. Maybe you sell tickets to places that have no "seats", maybe you sell opera tickets with numbers, then you probably need a way for the user to see where the seat is situated, meaning you need to show them that thing they show when you pick a seat at the theatre.. who knows? I'm just telling some basic things. Such app can be very complex.

One more thing: about what happens if the user loses the connection or in any other event that will prevent the ticket being properly purchased: it varies depending on the language you pick for your backend server, but generally speaking you would need to implement (in the server code) a reasonable timeout for the operation to end and then return the ticket to the pool.

In a real app that I made with Firsetore and Python backend, for example, I have a mechanic that checks if the user logged on during the last 24 hours - it's needed for some other stuff. I store the last logon time in the user's document in Firestore (via `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP`) and check for the time gap by comparing it to the current time (on the backend) of course I make sure there's no timezone issue etc so the Firestore time is matching my backend. This is done to avoid any kind of client-side data manipulation, you know, some users love to try things..

Comment: So your suggestion would be to make the 5 min trigger etc. Clientside?

Comment: Nope, I've updated the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Ok thank you that makes sense and is probably also the right answer as it also solves the problem I am gonna upvote you answer to give you at least some reputations and hope other users will do so thanks for the answer sir

Comment: Thanks! I have also added some suggestions about the time problem that I overlooked in the initial answer. I suggest you looking into how to build a proper backend.. at least if you want optimal performance and save on reads/writes to the Firestore. I mean, having a lot of them would not scale well.. people optimise this however they can, naming vars in the store like "lct" instead of "lastConnectionTime" etc.